# unable to determine the selected cell using ng grid

Tags: angular-ui, ng-grid

Is actually possibile to find which is the selected cell in a ng grid component, after I enabled enableCellSelection?
  thanks,

Luca Morelli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but you could get notified upon clicking in a cell what row and column were selected using a cell template.

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5qXXV8S8QyV4I8kOF53n?p=preview

```
    var myCellTemplate = '<div ng-click="clicked(row.rowIndex,col.index)">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>';
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear it :)